# Spawn multiple cubes with Array data

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I want help with this problem of mine. Let's consider I want to spawn a Rubik cube (3 3 3). And I want the spawning to happen in this way where we pass 4 data to the game / every cube has 4 data like x,y,z,t where x,y,z are location coordinates & t is the type of the cube. For example let's say (0,0,0,r). I need a red cube to spawn where r is red to spawn at 0,0,0 in unity. Another example is (0,2,0,b) where I need a blue cube to spawn at 2 in y. Hope you guys get the idea. So, with data like this i want to spawn a 3*3*3 cube.

Why I want this kind of array is in the future if I want to spawn a 10  * 10 * 10 cube. I need such data so I can only spawn the outer layer of the cube and not the ones inside. To save performance issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds pretty straight forward:

```
public enum CubeType
{
    white,
    yellow,
    blue,
    red,
    green,
    orange
}

private readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<CubeType, Color> colors = new Dictionary<CubeType, Color>
{
    {CubeType.white, Color.white},
    {CubeType.yellow, Color.yellow},
    {CubeType.blue, Color.blue},
    {CubeType.red, Color.red},
    {CubeType.green, Color.green},
    {CubeType.orange, Color.orange},
}

// Size/Expands of one cube tile
public float cubeSize = 1f;
public GameObject prefab;
// Amount of layers/dimensions e.g. 3x3
public int dimensions = 3;

public void SpawnCube(int x, int y, int z, CubeType type)
{
    var cube = Instantiate (prefab, new (Vector3(x,y,z) - Vector3.one * dimensions / 2f) * cubeSize, Quaternion.identity);
    // Or whatever you want to do with the type
    cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = colors[type];
}
```

Comment: That's for the answer. I'm new to unity and learning and this is a great help! Thanks man